# django :UnicodeDecodeError: '

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want build a blog with Python 2.7 and Django 1.7.8.

When I use Django,I keep getting an error: *`UnicodeDecodeError`*.
 The relevant code is:

```
#coding: utf-8
from django.db import models
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And **`./manage.py makemigrations`** get an error:

```
    Migrations for 'blog':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Entry
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 124, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 143, in write_migration_files
    migrations_directory = os.path.dirname(writer.path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 222, in path
    return os.path.join(basedir, self.filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 80, in join
    path += '/' + b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I don't see what's going wrong, any idea? I already add *`coding:utf-8`* in top of code

Comment: Without a full stacktrace including files and line numbers involved, your error pasting is of no use.

Comment: It seems that `makemigrations` is trying to produce a migration name and that name is non-ascii. Do you have anything non-ascii in your data models, or in file names?

Answer (score 1):

do you have data in the models already?
if so, i am guessing you have some bad characters in there.
do you have a **unicode** or **str** method defined on the models?
if so, i suggest using them in a try statement  of sorts like this:

```
def __str__():
    try:
       return "%s" % self.title
    except:
       return "%s" % self.pk
```

when you see only the PK, you will know that your 'title' field has bad data.
extend this to include whichever fields you want to display, not just title.

Comment: Nothing data in models.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like it fails when joining the path?

maybe you have folder names that can't be converted to ascii?

also , consider editing the file that is having the error? maybe add a print statement just before the line that fails that shows what is trying to be joined?

edit the file mentioned below, add the print statement to see what is trying to be joined?

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 80, in join
path += '/' + b
```